# Python--best way to use "open" command with in-memory str

Tags: python, python-3.8, temporary-files

I have a library I need to call that takes a local file path as input and runs open(local_path, 'rb'). However, I don't have a local file--I have an in memory text string. Right now I am writing that to a temp file and passing that, but it seems wasteful. Is there a better way to do this, given that I need to be able to run open(local_path, 'rb') on it?

Current code:

```
    text = "Some text"

    temp = tempfile.TemporaryFile(delete=False)
    temp.write(bytes(text, 'UTF-8'))
    temp.seek(0)
    temp.close()
    
    #call external lib here, passing in temp.name as the local_path input
```

Later, inside the lib I need to use (I can't edit this):

```
    with open(local_path, 'rb') as content_file:
            file_content = content_file.read()
```

Comment: Look at StringIO

Comment: Can you change the library? If not, `NamedTemporaryFile` is your only reasonable option; the library won't be able to accept an `io.BytesIO` or `io.StringIO` if it's designed to accept the name of a file to read from disk.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Not without copying the entire thing (many many files) in order to change just the one open() line. Ok, so the temp file is indeed the best way? I can change it to Named.

Comment: @Kitkat Yes, after reconsidering my initial comment/answer, I was incorrect. You have to create a temporary file so that you can pass its path into the library function. `NamedTemporaryFile` may or may not be better for you than `TemporaryFile` depending on your exact needs.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: Yeah, originally I was thinking `NamedTemporaryFile` only, but `TemporaryFile` might work, given `open` can receive a file descriptor; use `TemporaryFile`, and pass `os.dup(temp.fileno())` to the library API (the `os.dup` allows their `open` to close the fd without closing your copy of it). If it needs the string name for other reasons, that won't work, but `open` will accept file descriptors.

Answer (score 1):

Since the function you call in turn calls `open()` with the passed parameter, you must give it a `str` or a `PathLike`. This means you basically need a file which exists in the file system. You won't be able to pass an in-memory object like I was originally thinking.

Original answer:

I suggest looking at the `io` package. Specifically, `StringIO` provides a file-like wrapper on an in-memory string object. If you need binary, then try `BytesIO`.

Comment: I tried passing a StringIO but got this: "TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.StringIO". I'm not sure this works with open(), unless I'm passing the wrong thing.

Comment: @Kitkat Oh right...you need a file name or path in order to open it.